# LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8 Not supported

Tags: libreoffice, locale

My LANG is pt_BR, when I start any of the components of LibreOffice I see messages stating that LOCALE is not supported. When trying to open files in docs, I do not see files with accented names.

LibreOffice 5.3

Ubuntu 16.04

```
$ locale
LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=pt_BR:pt:en
LC_CTYPE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: I think you want this: https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=pt_BR.UTF-8&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=uiuaWKiqNJPW8AflsI3oCQ#channel=fs&q=broffice+for+linux but I can't read the pages to do a good check for you.

Comment: This sounds odd to me. Are you sure that you have the latest version of all packages? `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: I'm a compulsive updater! I always update my machines every day!